# SoapHttpClientProtocol disable ssl certificate validation

Tags: .net, soap, web-services

I need to tell my C# soap web service consumer to not validate the certificate and just accept it.  Is this possible?

Why: we publish a https-only web service.  A client needs to consume it but has some kind of firewall/proxy (WebSense?) which does something to the certificate to make it fail validation.  At this point I don't even know the details of *what* it does, but the customer appears to be ok with forfeiting the benefits of SSL, so I'm looking for a workaround.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

http://blog.jameshiggs.com/2008/05/01/c-how-to-accept-an-invalid-ssl-certificate-programmatically uses `ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback` to disable the certificate validation.

See ["The remote certificate is invalid according to the validation procedure." using Gmail SMTP server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/777607/the-remote-certificate-is-invalid-according-to-the-validation-procedure-plea) for a similiar question with the same answer.

Comment: Broken link... And that's why we copy the answer to SO.