# Error when sending email

Tags: asp.net, error-handling, smtp, email-validation

I have written a ASP.NET to sent SMTP mail for every 12 hours .It works fine in my office server but when i run the solution  in my clients server it shows me an error "**The remote certificate is invalid according to the validation procedure**". what will the problem and what is the solution for it?

Comment: It doesn't "shows you an error", it throws an exception. Please post the full exception.

Comment: Is the client using a self signed certificate for their mail server?  One of these is most likely to be the issue: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9983342/264607

Answer (score 0):

**There are a few questions out there already** :

(Great Feedback on what to check)
[The remote certificate is invalid according to the validation procedure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9983265/the-remote-certificate-is-invalid-according-to-the-validation-procedure/9983342#9983342)

(Code To Run on non-prod to get past errors)
["The remote certificate is invalid according to the validation procedure." using Gmail SMTP server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/777607/the-remote-certificate-is-invalid-according-to-the-validation-procedure-using)

(Additional Info)[The remote certificate is invalid according to the validation procedure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3453125/the-remote-certificate-is-invalid-according-to-the-validation-procedure)

**If Those Don't Work**

*Try adding the certificates on the server*

1. Save the certificate to your computer you need to add the
   certificate too.
2. Start -> Run -> MMC This will open the Microsoft
   Management Console
3. Go to File -> Add/Remove Snap-in... Select
   Certificates from the Available snap-ins: box and click Add >
4. You will have three options (User,Service,Computer), select Computer
   account and hit Next >.Hit Finish to close the dialog, and OK to
   close the snap-in dialog
5. Right click Trusted Root Certification
   Authorities -> All Tasks -> Import...
6. Hit Next >, browse the certificate, and hit next until the dialog closes and you have
   successfully added the certificate.

*Run a Trace to See Error Message*

Add the following to your web.config. (Taken from [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jpsanders/archive/2009/03/24/my-favorite-system-net-trace-configuration-file-dumps-process-id-and-date-time-information.aspx))

```
<system.diagnostics>
    <trace autoflush="true" />
            <sources>
            <source name="System.Net">
                    <listeners>
            <add name="System.Net"/>
                    </listeners>
            </source>
            <source name="System.Net.HttpListener">
                    <listeners>
            <add name="System.Net"/>
                    </listeners>
            </source>
    <source name="System.Net.Sockets">
                    <listeners>
            <add name="System.Net"/>
                    </listeners>
            </source>
    <source name="System.Net.Cache">
                    <listeners>
            <add name="System.Net"/>
                    </listeners>
            </source>
            </sources>
    <sharedListeners>
            <add
             name="System.Net"
             type="System.Diagnostics.TextWriterTraceListener"
              initializeData="System.Net.trace.log"
             traceOutputOptions = "ProcessId, DateTime"
            />
    </sharedListeners>
<switches>
    <add name="System.Net" value="Verbose" />
    <add name="System.Net.Sockets" value="Verbose" />
    <add name="System.Net.Cache" value="Verbose" />
    <add name="System.Net.HttpListener" value="Verbose" />
</switches>
</system.diagnostics>
```

This will give you a closer look at what's wrong. ie. name mismatch, etc.. Be sure to change the **initializeData="System.Net.trace.log"** to location of your log and make sure network service has r/w access.