# smtp.send method throws exception

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, web-config, smtpclient

I am using .net version 3.5 for sending mails though my web application

I get the following error:

> The SMTP server requires a secure connection or the client was not authenticated. 
>   The server response was: 5.7.1 Client was not authenticated

What could be causing this?

Answer (score 2):

Source from here http://www.systemnetmail.com/faq/4.2.aspx

```
//create the mail message
MailMessage mail = new MailMessage();

//set the addresses
mail.From = new MailAddress("me@mycompany.com");
mail.To.Add("you@yourcompany.com");

//set the content
mail.Subject = "This is an email";
mail.Body = "this is the body content of the email.";

//send the message
SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient("127.0.0.1");

//to authenticate we set the username and password properites on the SmtpClient
smtp.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("username", "secret"); 
smtp.Send(mail);
```

EDIT: This error means what it's written: smtp server needs authentication information (username and password). So, you need set SmtpClient.Credentials.

Comment: Have you considered adding a narrative to explain what the error is?

Comment: Are you using exchange server to send mail?

Comment: @ Alireza Maddah : yes i am using exchange server

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
smtpclient.EnableSsl = true;
```

Comment: iths giving this error now : The remote certificate is invalid according to the validation procedure.

Comment: @kumar check this out [a hack](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/777607/the-remote-certificate-is-invalid-according-to-the-validation-procedure-plea)

Answer (score 0):

> The SMTP server requires a secure
>   connection or the client was not
>   authenticated. **The server response
>   was: 5.7.1 Client was not
>   authenticated**

so you need to authenticate by adding credentials

```
smtpClient.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("username", "password");
```

Comment: then the credentials you supplied are likely invalid.