# The remote certificate is invalid when trying to remotely connect

Tags: c#, asp.net, ssl

I have an asp.net 4.0 script that I wrote that basically goes to grab an RSS feed from a secured site (we use a SSO solution). The script posts the correct credentials to the form and collects all the cookies, and then makes the request again with those cookies. The problem I am encountering is that when I request it from server I am getting the error `"The remote certificate is invalid according to the validation procedure."`

After talking with one of our guys that deals with the certificates he said that this has something to do with the type of certificate we purchased. Basically he told me there is nothing he can do on his end.

My question is what can I do to stop this error from appearing and let my script work?

```
            CookieContainer cookieJar = new CookieContainer();

            HttpWebRequest wr = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create("OURADDRESS");
            wr.UserAgent = "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 5.1; .NET CLR 3.5.30729;)";
            wr.Method = "POST";
            wr.Accept = "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8";
            wr.Headers.Add("Accept-Charset: ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.7");
            wr.KeepAlive = true;
            wr.Headers.Add("Keep-Alive: 300");
            wr.AllowAutoRedirect = false;

            wr.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";

            wr.CookieContainer = cookieJar;

            StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(wr.GetRequestStream());
            sw.Write("USER=" + UserName + "&PASSWORD=" + Password);
            sw.Close();

            HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)wr.GetResponse();

            foreach (Cookie cookie in response.Cookies)
            {
                cookieJar.Add(new Cookie(cookie.Name.Trim(), cookie.Value.Trim(), cookie.Path, cookie.Domain));
            }

            HttpWebRequest request2 = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(RssFeedLink);
            request2.UserAgent = "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 5.1; .NET CLR 3.5.30729;)";
            request2.Method = "GET";
            request2.Accept = "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8";
            request2.Headers.Add("Accept-Charset: ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.7");
            request2.KeepAlive = true;
            request2.Headers.Add("Keep-Alive: 300");
            request2.CookieContainer = cookieJar;

            request2.ContentType = "text/html";

            HttpWebResponse response2 = (HttpWebResponse)request2.GetResponse();
            StreamReader reader2 = new StreamReader(response2.GetResponseStream());
```

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this question (["The remote certificate is invalid according to the validation procedure." using Gmail SMTP server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/777607/the-remote-certificate-is-invalid-according-to-the-validation-procedure-using)) elsewhere on SO. However, the solution works here too:

```
            ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = (s, certificate, chain, errs) => true;
```