# make https request to wcf service: The remote certificate is invalid according to the validation procedure

Tags: c#, asp.net, wcf, iis-7

I have a service hosted over http/https on my local machine. When I consume the service over http it works perfectly. It also works when I make https request on ajax. But it's not work, when I try to consume it from code behind of client app. It shows the an error message as follows:

```
"The remote certificate is invalid according to the validation procedure"
```

Can somebody help me out?

Comment: possible duplicate : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/777607/the-remote-certificate-is-invalid-according-to-the-validation-procedure-using

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is because, the certificate you use on your local IIS, is a virtual one.
Probably, you will not get it in real time.
There are several hacks available to make it work locally.

NOTE: Never ever do this on production...

Add following code segment(an event handler), before calling any method of service.

```
 ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback +=
        EasyCertCheck;

 bool EasyCertCheck(object sender, X509Certificate cert,
   X509Chain chain, System.Net.Security.SslPolicyErrors error)
    {
        return true;
    }
```