# Are/can SSL certificates be specific to the service (e.g. server uses different certificate for HTTPS than for SMTP/TLS)

Tags: email, ssl, exchange-server, smtpclient

I can't work out a definitive answer on this, but from searching I find two links which seem to indicate to me that a server (in this case it's MS Exchange as per the links) can have different certificates in place for https than for secure smtp/TLS.

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/bb851505(v=exchg.80).aspx
https://www.sslshopper.com/article-how-to-use-ssl-certificates-with-exchange-2007.html

I have [an issue which no-one has been able to help with here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26103890/getting-the-remote-certificate-is-invalid-according-to-the-validation-procedure) and this question is a follow on, in that I am coming to the suspicion that my first problem is that my machine trusts the https certificate, but not the one being used for smtp/TLS. But what I'm asking now, is that even possible?

Going through the [diagnostic steps here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jpsanders/archive/2009/09/16/troubleshooting-asp-net-the-remote-certificate-is-invalid-according-to-the-validation-procedure.aspx?Redirected=true) shows me that the certificates in use when I access my mail server's web interface through https are fully trusted. However when I look at the debug of my c# process it is stating a completely different certificate issued by one of our servers to it's self (the server on which exchange is installed).

So... any one know if it's possible that I am thinking along the right lines... is it possible that when I do an https connection I get one certificate and when I use the .net SMTP client I get a completely different certificate (from exactly the same address, but I assume a different port)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it possible that when I do an https connection I get one certificate and when I use the .net SMTP client I get a completely different certificate (from exactly the same address, but I assume a different port)?

Yes, you can have a different certificate for each listening socket on the machine, that is SMTP and HTTPS can use different certificates. On a machine with multiple hostnames you could even have multiple different certificates on a single socket, which get distinguished by the hostname (using SNI).

Comment: Thanks Steffen. That's good to know, I now have something to tell our guys who administer the servers and hadn't been able to help me with my certificate errors so far. I'm pretty certain now that this is the cause of my issue.