# What is the purpose of ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback?

Tags: c#, .net, email, certificate

Lately, I had faced an error while sending email:

> The remote certificate is invalid according to the validation procedure using

and I found a solution to this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/777607/the-remote-certificate-is-invalid-according-to-the-validation-procedure-using) which works perfectly but don't know what actually it does. So, can anyone explain me what the below code actually does? and why is the code referred as a hack?

Code:

```
ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback =
delegate(object s, X509Certificate certificate,
         X509Chain chain, SslPolicyErrors sslPolicyErrors)
{ return true; };
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is a delegate your provide to the `ServicePointManager` that determines if a certificate is valid or not. Returning `true` will say the certificate is always valid.

You have to know **this is a serious security risk**. Anyone can self-issue a certificate and do a man-in-the-middle attack.

Comment: No. Why should it? It just circumvents the applications certificate check.

Comment: is there any way to block "self-issuing of certificate"?