# The remote certificate is invalid when trying to send mail

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I'm trying to send user a password reset link but when it comes to the **Smtp.send** stage, I got error saying that **The remote certificate is invalid according to the validation procedure**.

I'm not using Gmail to send this, I'm using our own domain mail server. Will it be issue for this matter ?

this is the sample of the code.

```
var smtp = new SmtpClient {
  Host = "mail.sample.com",
    Port = 587,
    EnableSsl = true,
    DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network,
    UseDefaultCredentials = false,
    Credentials = new NetworkCredential(fromEmail.Address, fromEmailPassword)

};
using(var message = new MailMessage(fromEmail, toEmail) {
  Subject = subject,
    Body = body,
    IsBodyHtml = true
})

smtp.Send(message);
```

Comment: Is the certificate valid? Is the date and time on the client machine correct?

Comment: @Llama Date and times are correct, I have googled the issue, there are some threads that  need to manually add certificate to the project. but couldn't find a proper guide to do that. Not sure same issue I got also

Answer (score 1):

I resolved it by adding these codes to mine

This line added before the `using(var message = new MailMessage(fromEmail, toEmail) {`

```
 ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback =new RemoteCertificateValidationCallback(ValidateServerCertificate);
```

and this method

```
public static bool ValidateServerCertificate(object sender, X509Certificate certificate, X509Chain chain, SslPolicyErrors sslPolicyErrors) {
  if (sslPolicyErrors == SslPolicyErrors.None)
    return true;
  else {
    return true;

  }
}
```

This resolved my issue. Main link ["The remote certificate is invalid according to the validation procedure." using Gmail SMTP server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/777607/the-remote-certificate-is-invalid-according-to-the-validation-procedure-using)

Comment: Be aware that this means that your whole application no longer validates the authenticity of any SSL certificate it encountered. So if you are working with https://api.some.bank and somebody manages to intercept your application's connection, they can substitute a fake SSL certificate and your application will never know. You should modify `ValidateServerCertificate` to specifically validate your mail server's certificate, and if it's not that one default to the standard validation. Or, the all-round better solution is to use a valid certificate on the server.

Comment: @Llama I Didn't knew that part. So can you explain me how to use a valid certificate to the server ?

Comment: As explained by @DiplomacyNotWar, this is not a solution. This is a workaround that can be used during development. Please, do not use this code in production.